# are minimal subdistributions determined by their support?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $Z$ be a finite set and $\mathcal S$ be a finite set of vectors in $Z^n$.

For each $z\in Z$ let $x_z$ be a formal variable.  A **distribution** (please excuse abuse of language) $d \in \mathbf N^n$ is a vector with nonnegative integer entries, not all zero, such that the set $\{\sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_{s_i} | s\in \mathcal S\}$ consists of a single element.

For example, if
$$\mathcal S = \{(1, 2, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 1)\},$$ then $d=(1,1,0,0)$ is a distribution, and so is $(1,0,1,1)$.  If $$\mathcal S = \{(1,1,2,3),(1,2,1,3),(2,3,3,1)\},$$ then $(1,1,1,2)$ is a distribution.

A distribution $d$ is **minimal** if there is no distribution $d'$ such that $d'_i \leq d_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $d' \neq d$.

The distributions in the examples above are minimal.

I am looking for a set $\mathcal S$ with the following properties:

- there are no two positions $1\leq i < j\leq n$ with $s_i = s_j$ for all $s\in\mathcal S$.
- there are two minimal distributions $d\neq d'$ on $\mathcal S$ such that $d_i > 0$ if and only if $d'_i > 0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Note that, without the first requirement, there are trivial examples of such sets.
For example, let $$\mathcal S = \{(1,1,2,2,2,1), (1,1,2,2,1,2), (1,1,2,1,2,2), (1,1,1,2,2,2), (2,2,1,1,1,1)\}.$$  Then $d = (2,1,1,1,1,1)$ and $d'=(1,2,1,1,1,1)$ are minimal distributions.  The first condition is violated, because $s_1 = s_2$ for all $s\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: Alternatively, one can associate with each element $s$ of $\mathcal S$ a $|Z|\times n$ matrix $s = (\delta_{s_i = z})_{z\in Z, 1\leq i\leq n}$.  Then the distributions are precisely the vectors with nonnegative integer entries in the intersection of the kernels of $s-s^0$ for some fixed element $s^0\in\mathcal S$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, could you please elaborate on your idea? I don't see why this set should admit any distribution.  For example, it contains $(2, 4993, 2)$ and $(4,4986,4)$, so all entries are different.  Apart from that, in this particular example we would have $x = z$ for all solutions (but I guess this could be fixed by choosing different equations).

Comment: @FedorPetrov, I hope I did not make a mistake - I don't see why $(1,2,6)$ would be a distribution.  For $s = (2, 4993, 2)$, and $d=(1,2,6)$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_{s_i} = x_2 + 2x_{4993} + 6 x_2$, whereas for $s = (4, 4986, 4)$ it is $x_4 + 2x_{4986} + 6 x_4$.

Comment: Sorry, when finishing reading the post I forgot about these variables and thought only about simple scalar products

Comment: Well, then what if we take $Z=\{0,1\}$ and all sequences $(t_1,\ldots,t_{100})$ of length 100 satisfying something like $\sum i t_i=A$, $2t_1+\sum_{i>1} t_i=B$ for suitable $A, B$ about 2500 and 50 respectively?

Comment: Wow, cool!  The smallest example I could find is with vectors of length $10$ and $A=20$, $B=4$!  Do you want to put that as an answer?  Follow-up question: can we also find such an example, if additionally the frequencies $\sum_i d_i x_{s_i}$ are required to be the same?

Comment: Something similar should work. What if the coefficients are, say, 1111111122222222 in the first equation and 1111222222221111 in the second, and the weighted sum is the same (and about average) for both?

Comment: Indeed, the smallest example I could find is with coefficients $(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)$ and $(1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1)$.  The set $\mathcal S$ has size 11 in this case.  This kills any hope :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from the comments:

there are examples of the following type: $Z=\{0,1\}$, the set $\mathcal{S} $ consists of sequences $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ satisfying two different relations of the form $\sum c_i t_i=C$, where $c_i$ are positive integers and $C$ is a positive integer (it is natural to choose it close to $\frac12 \sum c_i$). Then $(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ is a distribution, and it is easy to come up with example when two such distributions are both minimal and other conditions hold.